# ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous' Logistic Regression

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, logistic-regression

Trying to Perform logistic regression on Fuel Economy Dataset

[image]

But getting this error:

```
ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'
```

Code:

```
X = fuel.drop('Fuel Economy (MPG)', axis=1).values
y = fuel['Fuel Economy (MPG)'].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X = sc.fit_transform(X)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30)

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logir = LogisticRegression()

logir.fit(X)
```

Comment: maybe you are using class for discrete logistick regression on contunious data?

Answer (score 1):

Logistic Regression is for classification problems and can only be used with discrete or categorical values. Here I guess you are trying to predict a car's **fuel economy** based on its **horsepower**, so you are predicting a continuous value. For this you should use a Regression algorithm like **Linear Regression** or **SVR**.

To learn more about Linear Regression check out [this article](https://www.ml-concepts.com/2022/01/26/4-linear-regression-formulas-explanation-and-a-use-case/) on [ml-concepts.com](https://ml-concepts.com).

Comment: Can i perform clustering ?

Comment: @Pallab No that's another classification algorithm. You need Regression algorithms for this problem